# Swift unit testing: async

Tags: swift, xcode, asynchronous

I'm having trouble getting my unit tests right, I want to check it the data is in my struct, I can get my function to print out how many items there are however the test fails because the expectation doesn't come back.
I know I need to use

```
XCTAssertNotNil(self.players.countPlayers)
```

heres my function title

```
public func getPlayer(completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> (Swift.Void)
    ) throws{
    let jsonUrl: String = "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/78/players"
    //print(jsonUrl)
    // NSURL sessions allow us to download data using HTTP for APIs
    // a NSURL which contains a correct resourse
    guard let leagueURL = NSURL(string: jsonUrl)else{
        print("error creating string")
        throw JSONError.InvalidURL(jsonUrl)
    }
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: leagueURL as URL) {data, responce, error in

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as!   NSDictionary
                self.searchLeague = []
                for item in json["players"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]{
                    guard let name = ((item["name"]!) as? String) else{
                        throw JSONError.InvalidKey("invalid player name")
                    }
                    guard let position = ((item["position"]!) as? String) else{
                        throw JSONError.InvalidKey("invalid player position")
                    }
                    let jerseyNumber = ( ((item["jerseyNumber"]!) as? String) ?? ("No Assigned jersey number") )

                    guard let dateOfBirth = ((item["dateOfBirth"]!) as? String) else{
                        throw JSONError.InvalidKey("invalid player DOB")
                    }
                    guard let nationality = ((item["nationality"]!) as? String) else{
                        throw JSONError.InvalidKey("invalid player DOB")
                    }
                    let marketvalue = ( ((item["marketValue"]!) as? String) ?? ("Market value info not available"))
                    self.searchPlayer.append(Player(name: name, position: position, jerseyNumber: jerseyNumber, dateOfBirth: dateOfBirth, nationality: nationality, marketValue: marketvalue))
                }
            }catch{
                print("error thrown: \(error)")
            }
        print("Num of Players \(self.searchPlayer.count)")
        }
    task.resume()

}
```

and my Test

```
    func testGetPlayers(){
         let expectations = expectation(description: "Wait for exception")
         try! self.players.getPlayer{_,_,_ in
          expectations.fulfill()
    }
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 5) { error in
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've successfully demonstrated why unit testing is a good idea.

You've found a serious bug in your `getPlayer` method - you never call the completion handler.

You should be calling the `completionHandler` closure with the appropriate arguments from various places within your `getPlayer` method depending on whether you successfully process the data or encounter an error.